# How to select a tag from app in a components or views?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my App.vue, I created a color input, which is placed in my nav tag.
It allows me to change the background color.
It's the body tag of the DOM, so no problem.

In my local storage I keep the color defined so that it is saved during a refresh.

But if I want to create another input color to modify, for example, the color of one of my cards (which is in a component or in a view), I cannot catch the corresponding tag.

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <nav>
          ...
        <div class="color">
            <input type="color" id="colorInput">
            <font-awesome-icon input type="button" id="colorButton" :icon="['fas', 'paintbrush']" @click="changeColor()" />
        </div>
    </nav>
    <router-view/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    components: {},
    methods:{
        changeColor() {
            let color = document.getElementById("colorInput").value;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
            console.log(color) 
            localStorage.setItem('background', color);
        }
    },
    created(){
        let test = localStorage.getItem("background");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = test;
        console.log(test)
        
    }
}

</script>
```

I tested :

- With `querySelector`
- Put a `ref` attribute in the targeted tag then `this.$refs."refname".style.backgroundColor` but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Use v-model and a watcher like this: ([live example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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))

```html
<script>
export default {
    data () {
      return {
        colorInput: undefined
      }
    },
    watch: {
      colorInput(color) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
        localStorage.setItem("background", color)
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.colorInput = localStorage.getItem("background")
    }
}
</script>

<template>
  <input type="color" v-model="colorInput">
</template>
```